# sqoop export from hive partitioned parquet table to oracle

Tags: hive, sqoop, parquet

is it possible to do sqoop export from parquet partitioned hive table to oracle database?

our requirement is to use processed data to legacy system that cannot support hadoop/hive connection, thank you..

tried:

```
sqoop export -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=root.hsi_sqm \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:sid \
--username abc \
--password cde \
--export-dir '/user/hive/warehouse/stg.db/tb_parquet_w_partition/' \
--table UNIQSUBS_DAY
```

got error:

```
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Descriptor location does not exist: hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/stg.db/tb_parquet_w_partition/.metadata
org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Descriptor location does not exist: hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/stg.db/tb_parquet_w_partition/.metadata
    at org.kitesdk.data.spi.filesystem.FileSystemMetadataProvider.checkExists(FileSystemMetadataProvider.java:562)
    at org.kitesdk.data.spi.filesystem.FileSystemMetadataProvider.find(FileSystemMetadataProvider.java:605)
    at org.kitesdk.data.spi.filesystem.FileSystemMetadataProvider.load(FileSystemMetadataProvider.java:114)
    at org.kitesdk.data.spi.filesystem.FileSystemDatasetRepository.load(FileSystemDatasetRepository.java:197)
    at org.kitesdk.data.Datasets.load(Datasets.java:108)
    at org.kitesdk.data.Datasets.load(Datasets.java:140)
    at org.kitesdk.data.mapreduce.DatasetKeyInputFormat$ConfigBuilder.readFrom(DatasetKeyInputFormat.java:92)
    at org.kitesdk.data.mapreduce.DatasetKeyInputFormat$ConfigBuilder.readFrom(DatasetKeyInputFormat.java:139)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JdbcExportJob.configureInputFormat(JdbcExportJob.java:84)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:432)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.exportTable(OracleManager.java:465)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:80)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

is there any correct approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi for those encountering the same problem as me, here is my own solution (this could be vary depends on your environment)

1. write hive data to hdfs directory, you can use insert overwrite directory command in hive.
2. if you have deflated generated data from hive query in designated hdfs path, use this:
   `hdfs dfs -text <hdfs_path_file>/000000_0.deflate | hdfs dfs -put <target_file_name> <hdfs_target_path>`
3. sqoop export the inflated files using sqoop export command, don't forget to map your column according to your data type in target table

Answer (score 2):

We were facing similar issues.

Parquet creates .metadata folder. If you created the parquet using some other process , it might create like .metadata-00000 ( something similar ).

You can try renaming the folder to .metadata  and try.

Else, if this does not works you can try with hcatalog sqoop export.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response,
is it really safe to rename the folder? well i never use hcatalog, could you give me an example?

Comment: You can refer :- https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_data-movement-and-integration/content/sqoop_hcatalog_integration.html.

Comment: In case you run out of options, then we need to change the name of the folder.

Comment: Hi, this is my managed table directory structure, /user/hive/warehouse/stg.db/tb_parquet_w_partition/datex=2018-04-10

so which one should i rename?